# How to add class for li selected jquery ui autocomplete?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete, addclass

i am making form input with autocomplete multiple values and perfectly works, but i get some problem. i want if the first option I choose Alvin, then the second option I choose Yossy. so when I want to choose Yossy, option Alvin be there with a red background ( class active )

I tried to learn the method from jquery ui autocomplete, but I am still confused as to how it works.

this my code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var availableTags = [
    "Alvin Lim",
    "Khia Wijaya",
    "Suryo Guritno",
    "Adjie Hidayat",
    "Yossy Mo",
    "Iwan Prasetyo",
];

function split( val ) {
    return val.split( /,\s*/ );
}

function extractLast( term ) {
    return split( term ).pop();
}

$( "#account" )
// don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
.bind( "keydown", function( event ) {

    /* $('#keyword input#account').css('background','url(../image/arrow-up.png) no-repeat 95% center #bcbcbc'); */
    if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
        $( this ).data( "ui-autocomplete" ).menu.active ) {

        event.preventDefault();
    }
})

 .autocomplete({
    minLength: 0,
    source: function( request, response ) {
    // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
    response( $.ui.autocomplete.filter(
    availableTags, extractLast( request.term ) ) );
    },

focus: function() {
    // prevent value inserted on focus

    return false;
},


select: function( event, ui ) {
    var terms = split( this.value );
    // remove the current input
    terms.pop();

    // add the selected item
    terms.push( ui.item.value );
    // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
    terms.push( "" );
    this.value = terms.join( ", " );
    return false;
}


});
});
```

anyone can help me?
thanks in advance,
regards :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have'nt checked it out mate,this is juz a work-around.There might be other correct ways of doing it.But i think something like this might help u mate :)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var terms;
    var availableTags = [
        "Alvin Lim",
        "Khia Wijaya",
        "Suryo Guritno",
        "Adjie Hidayat",
        "Yossy Mo",
        "Iwan Prasetyo",
    ];

    function split( val ) {
        return val.split( /,\s*/ );
    }

    function extractLast( term ) {
        return split( term ).pop();
    }

    $( "#account" )
    // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
    .bind( "keydown", function( event ) {

        /* $('#keyword input#account').css('background','url(../image/arrow-up.png) no-repeat 95% center #bcbcbc'); */
        if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
            $( this ).data( "ui-autocomplete" ).menu.active ) {

            event.preventDefault();
        }
    })

     .autocomplete({
        minLength: 0,
        source: function( request, response ) {
        // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
        response( $.ui.autocomplete.filter(
        availableTags, extractLast( request.term ) ) );
        },

    focus: function() {
        // prevent value inserted on focus

        return false;
    },


    select: function( event, ui ) {
        terms = split( this.value );
        // remove the current input
        terms.pop();

        // add the selected item
        terms.push( ui.item.value );
        // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
        terms.push( "" );
        this.value = terms.join( ", " );
        return false;
    }


    }).data('autocomplete')._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
        if($.inArray(item.label, terms) > -1 ){
         return $( "<li></li>" )
                .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
        .append( '<a class="selected">' + item.label + '</a>' )
                .appendTo( ul );
        }else{
                return $( "<li></li>" )
                .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
        .append( '<a>' + item.label + '</a>' )
                .appendTo( ul );
        }

        };
        //}
    });
```

Comment: thanks for reply, but if i change css li.ui-menu-item a{ background: red } ,it's doesn't change. if i change lu.ui-menu-item{ background: red } display is changed. I think <a> no effect on the display <li>, when I inspect element with my browser, there is only <li class ="ui-menu-item ui-state-focus" tabindex="-1"> Alvin <li>,

so i change .append( '<a class="selected">' + item.label + '</a>' ) be .append( '<li class="selected">' + item.label + '</li>' ) , it's doesn't work to. any suggestion for me??

Comment: ouh nice.. there any tag <a>. one question, why in my inspect element, nothing tag <a>? do you know why?

Comment: Glad to help, I really didn't get u mate..if this answer solved your problem please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer.

Comment: actually your answer very helpful to solve my problem. :) it's just that there are other problems, nothing tags <a> :( , when i checked http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ , there nothing tag <a> too..

Comment: so u want to remove the `a` tag..??

Comment: because i haven't <a> tag, so the code <a class="selected"> not work for me.. if i have <a> tag, your code has solved my second problem..

Comment: oh yeah, you are my hero.. thank you very much.. i had days in this case, and i'm still beginner for jquery.. thank you :)